# Submit-Button that scrolls with the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with lots of `<input type="text">` fields. Not every single one has to be filled. When the user decides he is ready, he should click on the submit button.
Normally I would put the submit button at the bottom and/or Top of the page.

But it would be great if the button would scroll down with the user.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking this is what you are looking for:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8wr4W/)

**CSS**

```
#button-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#content {
    height: 600px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="button-bar">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>    
</div> 

<div id="content">
    <!-- content goes here -->  
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

use css:

```
#mybutton {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `style="position: fixed"` to the button and put in some absolute values for `top` and `left`